# JavaScript Bookmarklet get url + title

Tags: javascript, php, bookmarklet

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now, and can't seem to get it right.

What I'm trying to do is create a bookmarklet which sends the page url + title to a php script. This php script then echoes said information.

I figured that this piece of code catches the url & title and should send it to the PHPFILE.php:

```
javascript:location.href='PHPFILE.php;
url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+';
title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

I then tried to echo this like so:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
echo $url + $title;
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing the `?` part of your URL path: `'PHPFILE.php;
?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must append parameters like this "phpfile.php?url=value1&title=value2"

```
javascript:location.href='PHPFILE.php?'+
'url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+
'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) the values to the php page.

However, your problem is probably a malformed url because of the ';' characters and whitespace. You could try:

```
javascript:location.href='PHPFILE.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```